# Send email error when exception with silex

Tags: php, silex

I want to send a email when an exception is throw from my controller (with Silex). I tried to create a function to reuse this email function everywhere. 
I can't access to this function properly .

I tried to create a service (with pimple) but it's doesn't work.

How to create a service or function properly ?

```
//MY CONTROLLER 
$json->post('/mycontroller', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    $app['db']->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true); 
        $app['db']->insert('table', $data);
        //PHP CODE
        $return = ['result' => $app['db']->lastInsertId()];
        $app['db']->commit();
        return $app->json($return);
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        emailError($e, $data, $request);

        return $app->json(['error' => 'error']);
    }

});

//EMAIL ERROR FUNCTION 
$emailError = function ($e, $data, $request = null) use ($app) {
    //recupération de l'utilisateur

    $sql = 'SELECT ... WHERE id = ?';
    $result = $app['db']->fetchAssoc($sql, array('idvalue'));

    $title = 'TITLE - ' . $request->getPathInfo() . '';
    $message =
        'path ' . $request->getPathInfo() . "\r\n" .
        'sql result :' . $result['column'] . "\r\n" .
        'data :' . json_encode($data) . "\r\n" .
        "\r\n \r\n" .
        $e->getMessage() . "\r\n" .
        $e->getFile() . "\r\n" .
        $e->getLine() . "\r\n" .
        $e->getCode() . "\r\n" .
        $e->getPrevious() . "\r\n" .
        $e->getTraceAsString();
    mail('email@domaine.com', $title, $message);
};


//SERVICE TRY
$app['emailError'] = $app->share(function  ($e, $data, $request = null) use ($app) {
    //emailError function code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should return object in function that is passed to share method, the purpose of share method is to create and initilize one copy of object on demand
Ex:

```
class MyEmailError {
    protected $app;

    public function __construct($app) {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function mail($e, $data, $request = null) {
        // your code
    }
}
$app['MyEmailError'] = $app->share(function() use($app) {
    return new MyEmailError($app);
});
$app['MyEmailError']->mail(...);
$app['MyEmailError']->mail(...);
```